# Find the roots of equation based on some geometry hints

Tags: roots

Plots of the equations $y = 8 - x^2$ and $|y|=\sqrt{8+x}$ are symmetric w.r.t. the line $y=-x$. We have to solve the equation $$8-x^2=\sqrt{8+x}$$

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y_1=8-x^2$ and $|y_2|=\sqrt{8+x}$ are symmetric w.r.t. the line $y=-x$ implies the tangent lines at the intersection points are reflected over $y=-x$.

Refer to the graph:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image: ![enter image description here]

> The line $y_1=ax+b$ is reflected over $y=-x$ to the line $y_2=\frac1ax+\frac ba$. It implies $a\cdot \frac1a=1$.

Reference: $y_1=8-x^2$ and $|y_2|=\sqrt{8+x}$ (or $y_2=\pm \sqrt{8+x}$).

Finding $x_2$ (blue lines): 
$$y_1'(x_2)\cdot y_2'(x_2)=1 \Rightarrow -2x_2\cdot \frac1{2\sqrt{8+x_2}}=1 \Rightarrow x_2=\frac{1-\sqrt{33}}{2}.$$

Finding $x_4$ (purple lines): 
$$y_1'(x_4)\cdot y_2'(x_4)=1 \Rightarrow -2x_4\cdot \left(-\frac1{2\sqrt{8+x_4}}\right)=1 \Rightarrow x_4=\frac{1+\sqrt{33}}{2}.$$

Finding $x_1$ and $x_3$ (red and green lines): 
$$\begin{cases}y_1'(x_1)\cdot y_2'(x_3)=1\\y_1'(x_3)\cdot y_2'(x_1)=1 \end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}-2x_1\cdot \frac1{2\sqrt{8+x_3}}=1 \\ -2x_3\cdot \left(-\frac1{2\sqrt{8+x_1}}\right)=1\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}x_1^2=8+x_3\\ x_3^2=8+x_1\end{cases} \Rightarrow \\
(x_1-x_3)(x_1+x_3)=x_3-x_1 \Rightarrow x_1=-1-x_3 \Rightarrow x_3^2+x_3-7=0 \Rightarrow \\
x_3=\frac{-1+\sqrt{29}}{2} \Rightarrow x_1=\frac{-1-\sqrt{29}}{2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

If $y=8-x^2$ and $|y|=\sqrt{8+x}$, then $y^2-y=(8+x)-(8-x^2)=x+x^2,$

so $y(y-1)+x(-1-x)=0,$ so $y(y-1-x)+x(y-1-x),$ so $(y+x)(y-1-x)=0,$

i.e., $y=-x$ or $y=1+x$.  Therefore $x$ must be a solution of $8-x^2=-x$ or $8-x^2=1+x$.

Can you solve these **quadratic** equations?  Note that you want solutions where $y=8-x^2\ge0$.

Comment: I just added an Edit explaining in a different way how the line with equation $y=x+1$ is naturally involved in this issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

We intersect the parabolas

$$y=8-x^2$$ and $$y^2=x+8.$$

Let us form a pencil of conics by the same four intersection points and find the one that degenerates in a pair of lines.

$$y+x^2-8+\lambda(y^2-x-8)=0$$ has a double point where (by canceling the gradient)

$$2x-\lambda=0,\\1+2\lambda y=0.$$

We draw $x,y$ and plug in the equation of the pencil,

$$-\frac1{2\lambda}+\frac{\lambda^2}4-8+\lambda\left(\frac1{4\lambda^2}-\frac\lambda2-8\right)=0$$ or

$$\lambda^3+32\lambda^2+32\lambda+1=0.$$

By inspection, $\lambda=-1$ is a root, giving the degenerate conic

$$(x+y)(x-y)+(x+y)=0.$$

The rest is straightforward (two quadratic equations; ensure $y\ge0$).

Answer (score 0):

This issue necessitates a graphical representation [image]

*Fig. 1 : Curves with equations $y=8-x^2$ (cyan and magenta), $y=\sqrt{x+8}$ (red) and $y=-\sqrt{x+8}$ (green). We have figured as well line with equation $y=x+1$ (see the solution by @J. W. Tanner).*

Initial equation $8-x^2=\color{red}{+}\sqrt{8+x}$ and its "twin equation" $8-x^2=\color{red}{-}\sqrt{8+x}$ are equivalent to :

$$(8-x^2)^2-(8+x)=0$$

Luckily, this 4th degree equation has the following factorization :

$$(x^2 + x - 7)(x^2 - x - 8)=0$$

Therefore, it remains to compute the roots of the two quadratic factors.

$$x_1=\dfrac12(-1-\sqrt{29}), \ 
\ x_2=\dfrac12(-1+\sqrt{29}), \ \ x_3=\dfrac12(1-\sqrt{33}) \ \text{and}
\ x_4=\dfrac12(1+\sqrt{33}).$$

Clearly, the solutions of the initial equation are the least extremes $x_2$ and $x_3$, whereas the other "spurious" ones $x_1$ and $x_4$ are roots of the twin equation.

---

Now, let us find back "geometrically" the elegant solution given by  @J.W. Tanner, involving the use of straight lines $y=-x$ (no question...) and $y=x+1$ (less intuitive...).

If you happen to know **pencils of conic sections**, consider the pencil (family of conic curves) given by linear combinations of the two parabolas' equations :

$$\alpha(y^2-8-x)+\beta(y-8+x^2)$$

It is well known that an equivalent description  in such a case is the set of curves passing by the four common points of the parabolas defining the pencil.

Taking $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta=-1$ gives

$$y^2-x^2-x-y=0 \ \iff \ (y+x)(y-x-1)=0 \ \iff \ \begin{cases}y&=&-x\\y&=&x+1\end{cases}$$

explaining that the union of straight lines with equations $y=-x$ and $y=x+1$ (a degenerated conic curve) belongs to the pencil and as such, passes through the four intersection points of the two parabolas.

Comment: Very nice; what about the point of intersection of red and magenta curves?

Comment: @J. W. Tanner : red and magenta curves aren't symmetrical wrt $y=-x$

Comment: They aren't, but isn't their intersection point another solution of the question?

Comment: I have taken into account your remark by restricting the domain to $(-\infty,0)$ and explaining why.

Comment: Can you show that the red and magenta curves intersect on the line $y=x+1$?

Comment: I see what you mean : the 4 intersections form a kind of kite. Their abscissas are precisely the roots of the fourth degree equation I mention in my answer. Concerning their ordinates, you remark is interesting.  I see a "computational" proof. Do you have a smart one ?

Comment: The crux of the resolution is the factorization of the quartic. How did you proceed ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust I used a CAS.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I have added an Edit to my solution explaining things in terms of pencils of conic sections.

Comment: @JeanMarie: I did it at the same time :-)

Comment: @Yves Daoust "Les grands esprits se rencontrent :-)". Interesting use of gradient for finding the adequate combination.

Comment: @JeanMarie: in fact, this pencil method is just the Descarte's factorization technique for the resolution of the quartic, with a geometric flavor. It reduces to a cubic equation (echoing that there can be three pairs of lines), then two quadratics.

Answer (score 0):

The given two equations are one and the same. They are swapped in $(x,y)$ with sign change.

I am sorry that I am not able to understand why a given repeated procedure should unconditionally be useful in  solution finding.

Is it a text-book problem? What is the topic about?

An indirect claim that any polynomial (or by implication any transcendental equation) can be solved by means of such anti-symmetric inverse function logic as means for a solution may be difficult to justify, or so it seems to me. $x+y=0$ etc... procedure maybe just associated with such operation performed.

The geometrical hint is just an observation not an indispensable input premise for solution,imho.

We have by the straight procedure indicated:

$$ 8-x^2= y= -x\quad \rightarrow x^2-x -8 = 0, $$

$$ x_1=(1-\sqrt{33})/2 ;\,  x_2 = (1+\sqrt{33})/2$$

The procedure adopted cannot be exhaustive. One needs to proceed with a conventional solution.
Resorting to squaring to remove radical will introduce extraneous solutions to be later removed.

$$ y= 8-x^2; \quad y^2 = x^4-16x^2+64 \tag1$$

$$ y^2=8+x \tag2 $$

Equate $y^2$ in 1) and 2)

$$ x^4-16 x^2-x + 56=0 \tag3$$

Two roots are found already and in order to find the other two factors/roots in the fourth order polynomial we can write:

$$x^4-16 x^2-x + 56 = (x^2-x-8)((x^2+\lambda x -7)$$

Evaluating undetermined coefficients after expansion we find *three* $\lambda$ values:

$$ \lambda = (1,-15,8) \tag 4$$

We take first value,  eliminating next two $ \lambda =(-15,8)$ as spurious/extraneous roots confirmed in a graphical method later ( not fully convincing though ) getting expressions for $y$

$$  y=(x^2-x-8) (x^2+x-7)=0  \tag 5 $$
$$  y_2=(x^2-x-8) (x^2-15 x-7)=0  \tag {5a} $$
$$  y_3=(x^2-x-8) (x^2+ 8x-7)=0  \tag {5b} $$

The other two real roots of second quadratic are 
$$ x_3= (-1+\sqrt{29})/2,\, x_4=(-1-\sqrt{29})/2 \tag6 $$

(5) is plotted (scaled down factor 100 on y axis) with all four real roots shown.

Please note that (5a) and (5b) are ***all valid solutions*** because there are ***four real valid roots*** in the all three sets which are calculated as above and found to be correct as per expectation on extended plot domains (not graphed here).

[image]

Comment: Did you mean the left side of $(\color{red}5)$ is plotted?

Comment: Yes, with scale factor 100 division on y-axis.